# How to assign a value of selection field to other selection field in a onchange method in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Just working on the following code to autofill a Selection field

calendar.event has a location field which is a selection field, trying to autofill it in my custom module based upon an onchange method.

I wanted to get the selected value in that selection field for a particular record into 'loc' field which is also a selection field in my custom module

```
def get_meet_dets(self, cr, uid, ids, meet_ref, context=None):
        val = {}
        res = []

        if meet_ref:
            for det in self.pool.get('calendar.event').browse(cr,uid,meet_ref,context=context):
                for asst in det.attendee_ids:
                    emp_id = self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('user_id','in',user_id)])
                    val = {
                        'empname' : emp_id[0],
                        'wk_mail': asst.partner_id.email,
                        'loc' : det.location,
                        }
                    res.append(val)
            val.update({'matp':res})
```

and 'loc' is a selection field in current class. Anyone having any idea on this?

Comment: This is really unanswerable ..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an existing **id** for your *loc* field, you can try `'loc' : det.location.id,`. I hope this can be helpful for you.

Comment: Did you try `'loc':det.location.id` ??? In .v8 you only need to do `self.loc = record_id`  where record _id is an integer, in otherway you could return a domain for your loc field.

Comment: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Can you edit your post for more details, please, show as your definitions.

Comment: Congrats...please share your answer  to other people learn how to do that.

Comment: The answer is same as that in the code i posted Juan Salcedo, only problem was both the selection field's key values were mismatching from each other